# Initializing variables in helper function

Tags: scala, null

Sometimes I'm building a class I want to have a `reset` function in. For instance

```
class DFA(val initialState:State) {
    var states = Map[State,State]()
    var currentState: State = initialState
    reset
    def reset {currentState = initialState}
}
```

Oops! Didn't your DRY bells ring? I'm setting `currentState` to `initialState` twice. Once in `reset` and once in the constructor. I can't just leave the `var`s uninitialized, or the compiler will complain.

Of course I could

```
class DFA(val initialState:State) {
    var states = Map[State,State]()
    var evilNullVariableWeMustNeverUse = null
    var currentState: State = evilNullVariableWeMustNeverUse
    reset
    def reset {currentState = initialState}
}
```

but I think that the downside of this is obvious.

In this simple case, it's not so bad, but if you have 5 variables, or more complex logic, it becomes obnoxious.

How can I design around this?

Comment: You can use '_' to set an initial value. Also, why is 'reset' a var? should be a def. Then you can call it in the constructor.

Comment: `var reset`, that's a typo right? As IttayD suggests you probably mean `def reset { ... }`. I really don't see how the first solution isn't the clearest expression of what's happening as well as intent. Except that it should be `class DFA(val initialState:State)` or `class DFA( initialState:State)` as it does not makes sense to reset to a possibly changing state. Kim's answer trade one `initialState` for an extra `reset`. IttayD's one still mentions `initial` 3 times. What's up with this DRY obsession?

Comment: In my solution, DFA mentiones initial only 2 times. Also, imagine that initial is computed and not a constructor argument, then with Resettable, there's no need to store it in the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe create a Resettable wrapper?

```
class Resettable[T](initial: T) {
  var value: T = initial
  def reset = value = initial
  def :=(other: T) = value = other
}

object Resettable {
  implicit def resettable[T](initial: T) = new Resettable(initial)
  implicit def fromResettable[T](r: Resettable[T]) = r.value
}
```

Then:

```
class DFA(initialState:State) {
    var states = Map[State,State]()
    var currentState: Resettable[State] = initialState
    def changeState(other: State)  = currentState := other

    def reset = currentState.reset
}
```

And:

```
val dfa = new DFA(new State)
val t: State = dfa.currentState
```

The benefits can be seen with:

```
class Something {
   val a: Resettable[Int] = 0
   val b: Resettable[String] = "hi"
}
```

There is no need to store `0` and `"hi"` in another variable in order to reset.

Answer (score 2):

Make it immutable, and have "mutating" methods return a new instance.

Then, if you know you may need to return to the initial condition at some point, just make sure you've held onto a reference to the object as initially configured.

Comment: It's less typesafe. If I do that, my DFA might get another DFA with different state-table. If I keep it mutable, then `val dfa = DFA.fromFile("f.dfa")` is always representing `f.dfa`, I can't assign it with `DFA.fromFile("b.dfa")` by accident. Unless of course I encode the state table in the type...

Answer (score 1):

```
class DFA(var initialState:State) {
    var states = Map[State,State]()
    var currentState: State = _
    var reset {currentState = initialState}
    reset
}
```

Comment: First it is set to null, but then the contructor calls reset, which sets it to its final value.

Comment: Yes. same as in my example. I'd love the compiler to allow me initializing variables in a function called from the constructor. But I guess it's impossible.

Comment: Oops, it was supposed to call reset. Now it does.